# Slide in div to push content

Tags: jquery, css

Here is a demo of the script I am using to bring in a menu form the left:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTFq/)

The DIV that slides in the from the left will need to push the divs called 'left panel' and 'right panel' out of the way so they slide also. So instead of the hidden DIV to come in and hover over the left panel it will need to push it too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: `I need the box that comes in to push out the left and right divs so they slide with the div as if they are in the way instead of the box to slide in on top of the left div.` ... Please fix your grammar so everybody knows what you are asking for :)

Comment: So I am looking for a show/hide push menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

In CSS, remove the `absolute` positioning and set `width` to 0%.

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    width:0%;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}
```

And then, animate the value of `width` instead of the value of `left`:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"width":"0%"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"width":"25%"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/X5mP3/

Also, here's an alternative solution, in which the value of the left margin is animated instead of the width (in that case though, depending on your actual code, you'll probably need to set `overflow: hidden` to some parent element to hide the div behind it): http://jsfiddle.net/652RY/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by animating container containing all the three div elements. Animate the conatainers left property with the amount of width your left side menu is having.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTFq/1916/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hidden">Here I am !</div>
    <div class="left">Left panel</div>
    <div class="right">Right panel</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#" id="slide">Show/hide Slide Panel</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
     if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"140px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
.left, .hidden {
    float: left;
    height:350px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-140px
}

.left {
    width: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index:1;
}

.hidden {
    width:25%;
    z-index:2;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}

.right {
    width:50%;
    float: right;
    height:350px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}

#slide{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
}
```